# Current as the time derivative of the charge

Tags: electrostatics, electric-current, charge

I have been told that the current $i$ can be defined as

$ i = \displaystyle\frac{dq}{dt} $,

where $q$ is the charge and $t$ is the time.

I do not understand this definition because, if the charges are moving so that the net charge remains constant in an infinitesimally thin cross-section of a wire, $q$ is constant with time and hence $dq/dt = 0$. That result would mean that no constant current can exist unless the charge change has a linear dependence with time (i.e. $q = q(t) \propto t$).

As I assume my reasoning is wrong, where is my mistake?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Electric current can be understood through the analogy of water flow.

Just as the 'water current' in a river is the amount of water which passes a point in a given time interval, similarly, the electric current can be understood as the amount of electric charge passing through an area in a given time interval.

Of course, the analogy is not entirely correct, since charges can be either positive or negative, but the analogy is useful if we 'define' the electric current in terms of the 'flow' of positive charges

[image]

So, for example, considering the electric current through a wire of cross section $A$, the amount of charge ${\Delta q}$ passing through this surface in a time interval ${\Delta t}$ allows us to 'define' the average electric current as:

$I_{avg}=\frac{\Delta q}{\Delta t}$

If amount of charge passing through the area every second remains constant, then $\Delta q$ is constant so the current is constant.

If the charge flow varies with time, then we can define the instantaneous current by taking the limit as $\Delta t\rightarrow0$ to get:

$i=\frac{dq}{dt}$

The concept of the 'instantaneous' current through a circuit is further complicated when we consider the current through a capacitor element, which requires the introduction of a displacement current to account for changes in electric displacement, the full description of which is given by Maxwell's equations.

Comment: Very nice answer! So when both protons and electron moves in opposite directions throught a surface then the current will not be zero. Because if we have a flow rate (as current) then we will have either a positive or negative flow. Consider electron's moving as positive charges in opposite directions makes perfect sense. As we know positive charges flow from low to high potentials, but if it were to observe positive charges to move in opposite directions this would make the current zero, irrespective of the fact that charges are moving.

Answer (score 1):

We define current as change in charge per time through an area $A$, not in and out of a volume. If the charge is moving through this area you get a current as expected because you have a net flow. If equally much charge passes through from both sides, the current is zero and the net charge is not moving.

Comment: When you say "equally much charge passes through both sides", do you mean that free electrons go across that area in the $+x$ and $-x$ directions, so that the moving net charge is zero?

Comment: Yes, there is only one area used in the definition. Electrons can pass through this area from both sides, and if equally many electrons pass from each side the net charge passing through is zero. Hence the current is zero.

Comment: Is it posible, in practice, that electrons go in the $+x$ and -$x$ directions simulataneously?

Comment: Yes. The random velocity for electrons is very large, but this velocity is neglected because electrons approach from both sides. Only the drift velocity will determine the current. In addition, remember that the cross section area may be very large.

Answer (score 0):

Realise that, in case of electric current, it is the *free electron* that moves while the nucleus stays fixed. Hence, when we say charge, in this case, we actually refer to the free electrons that are moving inside the wire.

We do not consider the positive nuclear charges. Obviously the net charge is $0$ across any cross section if we consider the positive charges; else there will be a non zero electric field inside the wire and the current flow will be in haphazard directions.

And, to add more, current is the *flow of charges* through a conducting wire. Since only the free electrons are mobile while the nuclei are not (from the frame of the observer standing outside the wire on the ground), the flowing charges are the electrons only and that is what matters most, as I have mentioned earlier.

Comment: I do not understand this sentence: " else there will be a non zero electric field inside the wire and the current flow will be in haphazard directions." Why would be non-zero electric field inside the wire?

Comment: If each cross section does not have equal number of positive and negative charges then there will be an excess of either positive or negative charges and as a result there will be an electric field inside the conducting wire which is improbable since the electric field inside a conductor is always zero. Also the excess charge will always flow in the direction of the electric field, the current will also be in that direction.

Comment: Thank you. Why do you say that it is improbable to have an electric field inside the conducting wire? I thought that if you have an _idle_ perfect conductor (no current flowing through it), there will not be field inside. Otherwise (non-perfect conductor and current flowing), there will be an electric field to move those free electrons inside the conductor. That current flow could come from a battery or an antenna. Is that wrong?

Comment: No.no. You are correct from your point of view. But you got me wrong. I wanted to say that if you could take an image of the electrons flowing through the conducting wire (hypothetically by some unknown mechanism) and then if you consider any cross section of the conducting wire at that particular instant, you will find that the total number of electrons in the cross section will be equal to the total number of protons present in the cross-section. So the net charge in the cross section will be zero. As result the external field will be cancelled by the field between charges inside the wire.

Comment: (Contd.) Hence there will be no *net* electric field inside the conducting wire in the transverse direction i.e. in the direction of the line joining the charges.

Comment: Okay. I think you are saying that, as the free electrons jump from one atom to another while flowing through the conductor, the _net_ charge will be zero in the cross section because there is the same amount of negative and positive charges at each point. However, I do not see why you say that _net_ electric field is zero inside the wire in the tranverse direction. Do you mean that it is not zero in the longitudinal direction?

Comment: By transverse, I mean the radial direction. However along the longitudinal direction or the axial direction, the electric field is non zero since it is this field that is accelerating the free electrons and hence generating the current.

Answer (score 0):

Current is not related to the charge "**in** an infinitesimally thin cross-section of a wire". Electrical current is the amount of charge that passes **across** that cross-section per unit of time.

If the current is constant, the last expression you show works:

$ I = \displaystyle\frac{q}{t} $,

If the current varies, your first expression is appropriate.

Comment: Okay. So these formulas indicate the total (acummulated) charge that passes across the cross-section during a lapse of time?

Comment: @baister. For direct current, yes. For AC it's somewhat more complicated but related. Sorry I'm not fascile with displaying equations, I couldn't insert a capital Greek delta. Put a delta in front of both the q and the t in the equation I show (as theo does). That version better states "how much charge flows past a point in a given amount of time".

Comment: Thank you. I got it. In case I wanted to use the limit equation ($\Delta t \rightarrow 0$), $q = q(t) = It$, I guess.